# App inappropriately unlocks or enables additional functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

My App is rejected by the reason :

"We found your app inappropriately unlocks or enables additional functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines"

"It may be appropriate to revise your app to use the In App Purchase API to provide content purchasing functionality. "

What I have done is as below:

[image]

As this app is for my specific customer companies to use, I only want the companies who get the Invitation Code from me to use my app. There is no charge. I don not know is it necessary to use the In App Purchase API instead? if it is true , can you give me some tips?

Comment: What does that text say in English?

Comment: @7usam "please enter in 11 digits of verification code"

Comment: From the App Store's perspective, there is no guarantee that you won't charge for those codes.  And they desperately want to maintain their monopoly on the world by holding developers to ransom.  So you'll probably have to find some other way to do this.

Comment: Did you put a working verification code in the review notes in the app submission?

Answer (score 3):

Your application cannot be used by members of the general public, and thus does not belong in the App Store.

If you only intend your application to be made available to a few specific people, you should use Ad-Hoc Distribution to make it available to them.

Comment: is there any In App Purchase API can afford my purpose? Because I think Ad-Hoc Distribution is mainly used for testing and as my customers increase, it is hard to do management

Comment: No. If you want anybody to be able to to pay to use your app, distribute it as a paid app. If you want to restrict who can use your app, in-app purchasing won't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Explain the purpose to the review team, sometimes they listen. 
Also, maybe have that message as a "login page" instead. Have a username and password rather than a verification code. The verification code message may look more like you are selling the app behind the AppStore. Also provide the review team with an access code / login details if you haven't already so they can actually review the app.